# Actionscript 3 - XML syntax?

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, syntax

Does anyone know how the XML syntax works in Actionscript 3? I copied over my XML file into AS so I can export an independent SWF, but it's giving me a whole bunch of syntax errors "1093: syntax error", on almost every single line.

```
var xml:XML = 
<images>
    <pic>images/3.png</pic>
    <painter>Painter name</painter>
    <title>画家1</title>
    <date></date>
</images>
<images>
    <pic>images/2.png</pic>
    <painter>Painter name</painter>
    <title>画家2</title>
    <date></date>
</images>
...
...
about 20 of these <images> sections
```

One of the parameters contains foreign characters.
I've already tried turning all the "<" ">" and quotation/apostrophes into the HTML code, still doesn't work...

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a root node.  That is not valid xml as it stands right now.

An easy fix is to just wrap the `<images>` nodes in a `<root>` node like so

```
val xml:XML = 
<root>
    <images>
        <pic>images/3.png</pic>
        <painter>Painter name</painter>
        <title>画家1</title>
        <date></date>
    </images>
    ...
</root>
```

If you want your XML to map directly to an XMLList, you can use an unnamed root node (*note this is not valid XML, but AS3 doesn't mind)

```
<>
    <images>
        <pic>images/3.png</pic>
        <painter>Painter name</painter>
        <title>画家1</title>
        <date></date>
    </images>
    ...
</>
```